# Using iTunes without Apple Quicktime on Windows

Tags: windows, itunes

Is it possible to install/use/update iTunes without also having to install the eternal hellspawn known as Apple Quicktime?

When you install Apple Quicktime, it installs its QTTask.exe executable to run automatically on startup (what the hell does that do anyway?). Not only that, but it keeps coming back if you remove it from the registry. It also immorally takes over media file playing on web browsers **without asking** (Screw you Apple!).

One solution I'm aware of is the heaven-sent "QuickTime Alternative", aka QTA. Is there a definitive catch-all tutorial for it?

BONUS: Even though iTunes is able to play along with QTA, every time you update to a new version of iTunes, you have re-uninstall Apple Quicktime, and then re-install QTA. Is there a workaround for this inconvenience?

Comment: I'd like to know the way to avoid this.  The way I do it is to manually de-install quicktime on every machine. I  actually produced an application that runs via Task Scheduler, to de-install quicktime.

Comment: Any ideas of a software that handles podcasts as effortlessly as iTunes?

Comment: Also, as an added bonus they install and run Bonjour without asking you too.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/install-itunes-without-quicktime-and-bonjour/) links to a custom installer which will install iTunes without the other stuff.

Comment: A more direct link: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=122101 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t purchase music via iTunes and only use it to import your CDs and such into your iPod, another option is to forego iTunes altogether. Redchair makes Anapod Explorer which is pretty good. Another one that works without installing anything on your system—and is free!—is vPod (which I don’t believe does photos or videos though).

Comment: I do use iTunes for the (VERY OCCASIONAL) exclusive buy. The main day-to-day use I have for it is the SUPER CONVENIENT Podcast Directory  download/sync and subscription management.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this because I do have QT installed with iTunes but I would assume there is a degree of dependency between the two, namely it's quite possible that iTunes would also use some of the QT APIs for video

As stated above I could be wrong but it's something to investigate before uninstalling QT